# Ethereum sidechain application

Tags: transactions, sidechain

I am developing a simulation that will be made millions of transactions, studying Ethereum, I realized that it would not be worth storing these transactions in the ethereum platform due to the cost of the transactions. In this way I realized that it would be more feasible to use a sidechain to perform the transactions, and to use the blockchain of the ethereum to store only the hash of the sidechain blocks.

Could you give me examples of sidechain clients that can be used in conjunction with the ethereum platform?

Is the idea of ​​storing only the hash of the sidechain blocks on the ethereum platform valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed this is a **valid direction** to avoid having to pay excessive cost for storage and transactions. This, combined with the limited throughput (speed) of transactions, is the reason why folks in the Blockchain community have started looking at sidechains technology. This is only one of the ways to scale when you have a vast amount of transactions (State Channels are another way).

When it comes to choosing a sidechain technology, there are currently **not that many that are production-ready** or even that allow you to simply play in a sandbox environment as a developer. My favourite one for its **ease of use and fast progress in development is definitely [Loom](https://loomx.io)**. Like Ethereum it uses the EVM, which makes it a breeze to move away from the mainchain and start developing on the sidechain.

Note that **[Lisk](https://lisk.io/) is also planning to release their sidechain** protocol soon.